# Cracked on i20 camshaft?

Tags: hyundai, camshaft, i20

Are those markings, tampered or cracks on the picture of Hyundai i20 camshaft normal???

[image]

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the part with GC stamped in it then that is part of the carrier for the camshaft and the marks are not a problem.

The camshaft you can see a small part, middle lowest part of pic with a polished surface and a silvery edge on the righthand side.

Comment: The marks on the camshaft carrier are remnants from when they cast the piece. As @Solar Mike said, they are nothing to worry about.